# Edit HTML with other HTML

Tags: html

So i have a Infoboard with some html sites. Now I like to switch this sites with a other html site with buttons. Is there a way to do this? I couldn't find some good article on the Internet about that. Thanks for Help and sorry for my bad English!

Comment: where is your code? We can't help you if your question is that broad and giving us no clue on what you have tried so far...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I think this about your question.*

For go to another HTML site, you should use the ' a ' element i mean:

```
<button><a href="yourHtmlFile.html" target="_self"> Click Here !</a></button>
```

**More info:**

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp

Comment: No this wasn't my question i know i can use a Element for this :) But i have two html sites. I wanna click a button on the first side and then the second side should change

Comment: Damn, that's so hard and you cannot do with HTML, you should use AJAX and i'm not sure.. and for sure Angular5 for SPA and learn about component data transfer